# Highlight typical elements in list?

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have a big sorted list and some of it is important, I want to visualize the position of these important elements.

```
RandomSeed[1234];
red = RandomInteger[10000, 100];(*important elements*)
point = Sort@RandomInteger[10000, 1000];(*all elements*)
pointColor = If[MemberQ[red, #], Style[#, Red], #] & /@ point;
ListPlot[pointColor]
```

[image]

I try some ways fails such as

- `ListPlot[pointColor, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.04]]`
- `pointColor = If[MemberQ[red, #], Style[#, Red, Thick], #] & /@ point;
  ListPlot[pointColor]`

but only this code:

```
ListPlot[pointColor, PlotStyle -> Blue] /. 
 RGBColor[0, 0, 1] -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.04]
```

[image]

So what the better way to visualize these important elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pointColor = If[MemberQ[red, #], Style[#, Opacity[1, Red], PointSize[Medium]], #]& /@ point;

ListPlot[pointColor, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.04]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a workaround, but if you don't have to generate random numbers and you already have the correct lists it would work better than trying to apply a sort of mask/style to one list: keeping the two lists separate before plotting is probably easier. 
You could also remove the important elements from the total list if you don't want to double plot them.

```
Position[point, #] & /@ red;
pos = Flatten[Select[%, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]];

important = Transpose[{pos, point[[pos]]}];

Show[
 ListPlot[point],
 ListPlot[important, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
RandomSeed[1234];
red = AssociationThread[RandomInteger[10000, 100] -> True];
point = Sort@RandomInteger[10000, 1000];
```

Get the positions `pos1` of important points:

```
pos1 = Pick[Range[Length[point]], Lookup[red, point, False]];
pos2 = Complement[Range[Length[point]], pos1];
```

Put the important points last in `Show` to get them on top of the other points:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[Thread[{pos2, point[[pos2]]}], PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Small]]],
 ListPlot[Thread[{pos1, point[[pos1]]}], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]